# Do I need to explicitly finish an Activity in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-finish

When I am starting a new activity do I need to explicitly finish the current activity or does android take care this ?

This is what I write in activity A to start activity B:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, BActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Should I end A by calling next line after above mentioned two lines ?

```
this.finish()
```

Comment: If an Activity is complete and the user is unlikely to return to it you should call finish() to free up the resources used by this Activity. Less memory wasted means a better app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In General no you shouldn't.

The difference will be if you call finish in Activity A, While the user is in Activity B if they press the back button they will go back to whatever they were doing before opening your application. If you instead do not call finish in Activity A they will go back to Activity A

If you **DO** call finish:

```
Activity A -> Activity B -> [user press back] -> Homescreen (or whatever activity is on the stack below activity A)
```

if you **DO NOT** call finish:

```
Activity A -> Activity B -> [user press back] -> Activity A
```

Answer (score 2):

No it is not compulsory.

```
finish()
```

finish method state that **"Call this when your activity is done and should be closed. The ActivityResult is propagated back to whoever launched you via onActivityResult()."**

reference link >> [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

```
 explicitly finish the current activity or does android take care this ?
```

It depends on your requirement if you wants activity A while coming back form activity B still there so you need not to call finish but if you does not want activity A when coming back form activity B then you should call finish ....